# $g(x)=x^2f(x)$ differentiable at $0$ given $|f(x)|\leq M$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $|f(x)|\leq M$ for an $M>0$ and all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $g(x)=x^2f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I need to show that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

With the definition of differentiability I got $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}$ = $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2f(h)}{h}$ = $\lim_{h \to 0} hf(h)$.

I also know that $f(h)$ is bounded by $M$, so as $h$ goes to $0$, $hf(h)$ also goes to 0. (Correct?)

**I do however not know if $f(h)$ is continous or differentiable, is this a prerequisite?**

Comment: "I do however not know if f(h) is continous or differentiable, is this a prerequisite?" ---- No, it's enough, that $f$ is bounded. The limit exists then independtly of other properties of $f$.

Comment: $hf(h)$ is bounded by $|h|\cdot |f(h)|\leq M|h|$, so you can conclude what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine to me. And no, we don't need any more niceness conditions on $f$. Boundedness is enough. *Any* function squeezed between $Mx^2$ and $-Mx^2$ (which is what $g(x)$ is), no matter how discontinuous it otherwise is, will be differentiable at $x = 0$. That is what you have proven, after all.

If you really want a nit-pick, you could be a bit more explicit about *how* $f$ being bounded by $M$ implies that $hf(h)\to 0$. Whether that's actually necessary (and if so, in how much detail), depends on your teacher / professor / TA, since deciding whether you've demonstrated the skill you need to demonstrate on tests and assignments is ultimately up to them.

Comment: To give you a small idea: if _I_ were correcting this on a test that I had administered, and it were a 5-point exercise, I might've deducted half a point, or I might not, depending on how I feel, and on whether all other students glossed over it like you did (at which point it's my teaching which should get point deductions instead). But you'd definitely get full score if this were a 2-point exercise.